# Django mod_wsgi apache

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

When I try to visit my Django site at http://www.satoshi.example.com/mysite I get a `503 Service Temporary Unavailable`.

The Apache error log says

```
[Tue Feb 28 07:11:09 2012] [error] [client 10.0.0.202] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=4756): Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'django' on '/etc/httpd/logs/wsgi.17555.4.1.sock' after multiple attempts.
```

Apache properly loads `mod_wsgi`

```
root@satoshi:~/html/mysite# apachectl -M | grep wsgi
 wsgi_module (shared)
Syntax OK
```

Apache loads `/var/www/html/mysite/apache/apache_django_wsgi.conf` which is

```
WSGIDaemonProcess django
WSGIProcessGroup django

<Directory "/var/www/html/mysite">
Order allow,deny
Options Indexes
Allow from all 
IndexOptions FancyIndexing
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /mysite "/var/www/html/mysite/apache/django.wsgi"

<Directory "/var/www/html/mysite/apache">
Order deny,allow
Allow from all 
</Directory>
```

This is the `/var/www/html/mysite/apache/django.wsgi`

```
import os
import sys 

paths = [ '/var/www/html/mysite',
          '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/',
]

for path in paths:
    if path not in sys.path:
        sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

One weird thing is that I found out I don't even need to `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` on my own `httpd.conf`. I think my `httpd.conf` is an extension of another configuration that already loaded `mod_wsgi`. Not sure if this matters.

Is there anything wrong with what I provided so far? Let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance!

=====================================================

Information requested by @jpic

```
root@satoshi:/var/www/html# ps aux | grep apache
root      4564  0.0  0.2 207636  5432 pts/9    S+   04:16   0:00 vi apache_django_wsgi.conf
apache    6006  0.0  0.7 365140 14820 ?        S    09:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6007  0.0  0.7 365140 14884 ?        S    09:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6008  0.0  0.7 365140 14888 ?        S    09:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6009  0.0  0.7 365140 14884 ?        S    09:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6010  0.0  0.7 365008 14784 ?        S    09:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6011  0.0  0.7 365008 14768 ?        S    09:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6012  0.0  0.7 365008 14748 ?        S    09:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6013  0.0  0.7 365140 14876 ?        S    09:53   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
apache    6112  0.0  0.7 365008 14756 ?        S    10:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
root      6116  0.0  0.2 207700  5492 pts/15   S+   10:06   0:00 vi ../apache/django.wsgi
apache    6181  0.0  1.5 713972 32136 ?        Sl   10:08   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd
root      8173  0.0  0.0 103300   848 pts/17   S+   23:39   0:00 grep --color=auto apache
```

User information (Did you mean `id`? `userid` was not found)

```
root@satoshi:/var/www/html# id apache
uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache)
```

`ls -la` information

```
root@satoshi:/var/www/html# ls -la /etc/ | grep httpd
drwxrwxr-x.   4 root 4.0K Feb 16 18:27 httpd/

root@satoshi:/var/www/html# ls -la /etc/httpd/
total 24K
drwxrwxr-x.   4 root 4.0K Feb 16 18:27 ./
drwxr-xr-x. 128 root  12K Feb 28 03:45 ../
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root 4.0K Feb 28 08:07 conf/
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root 4.0K Feb 16 18:28 conf.d/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root   19 Feb 16 18:27 logs -> ../../var/log/httpd/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root   29 Feb 16 18:27 modules -> ../../usr/lib64/httpd/modules/
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root   19 Feb 16 18:27 run -> ../../var/run/httpd/

root@satoshi:/var/www/html# ls -la /etc/httpd/logs/
total 528K
drwxrwxr-x.  2 root   4.0K Feb 28 09:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x. 19 root   4.0K Feb 27 06:51 ../
-rw-r--r--   1 root    17K Feb 28 10:08 access_log
-rw-r--r--   1 root    351 Feb  3 10:24 access_log-20120205
-rw-r--r--   1 root   1.8K Feb  7 01:39 access_log-20120212
-rw-r--r--   1 root   278K Feb 18 23:17 access_log-20120219
-rw-r--r--   1 root    85K Feb 22 08:38 access_log-20120226
-rw-r--r--   1 root    50K Feb 28 10:08 error_log
-rw-r--r--   1 root    14K Feb  5 03:28 error_log-20120205
-rw-r--r--   1 root   2.2K Feb 12 03:14 error_log-20120212
-rw-r--r--   1 root   9.4K Feb 19 03:28 error_log-20120219
-rw-r--r--   1 root   4.0K Feb 26 03:20 error_log-20120226
-rw-r--r--.  1 root      0 Oct 14 15:14 ssl_access_log
-rw-r--r--   1 root   3.1K Feb 28 09:53 ssl_error_log
-rw-r--r--   1 root   1.4K Feb  3 03:25 ssl_error_log-20120205
-rw-r--r--   1 root    237 Feb  5 03:28 ssl_error_log-20120212
-rw-r--r--   1 root   1.2K Feb 17 01:52 ssl_error_log-20120219
-rw-r--r--   1 root    237 Feb 19 03:28 ssl_error_log-20120226
-rw-r--r--.  1 root      0 Oct 14 15:14 ssl_request_log
srw-rw-rw-   1 apache    0 Feb 28 09:53 wsgi.17555.14.1.sock
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This issue is documented in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ConfigurationIssues#Location_Of_UNIX_Sockets

The solutions given by others of changing permissions are wrong.

The correct solution is to change where the socket files are kept to a location where Apache user can read them.

On systems which protect logs directory, they sometimes have a system in place to set back those permissions when you mess with them. As a result any change may only be temporary.

Comment: my experience is, that where ever you set the socket location, they will always have stricter permissions (e.g srwx------ www-data root ) and so you have to change socket permissions.

Comment: You don't need to and you don't have an ability to set the socket permissions because the name of the socket file changes dynamically over time based on process ID, Apache configuraton generation and daemon process group instance. IOW, it is not an unchanging name. As long as the directory is accessible to the Apache user it will all work as mod_wsgi will ensure that the actual socket files have the correct permissions.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I have changed configuration as per the link you provided but I still get the error "Unable to connect to WSGI daemon process 'wsgi' on '/var/run/wsgi.12116.0.1.sock' after multiple attempts"

Answer (score 2):

I have wrote this script to handle wsgi socket permission problem on apache2-mpm-itk

```
#!/bin/sh
# This script will fix apache wsgi socket permissions
# By default use standard socket location /var/run/apache2/wsgi
# 
# You have to add this script after success execute of start|restart|reload 
# commands in next files:
#   /usr/sbin/apache2ctrl
#   /etc/init.d/apache2

WSGISocketPrefix="/var/run/apache2/wsgi"

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
    echo "This script must be run as root" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

echo "Wait for other processes to start"
sleep 1
echo "Change wsgi socket permissions"
chmod 0766 ${WSGISocketPrefix}.*
```

Answer (score 0):

The user that is running the apache process doesn't seem to have permission to read/write from the specified location.

That is usually approached by setting the `WSGIDaemonProcess` and `WSGIProcessGroup` directives in the VirtualHost conf.

```
WSGIDaemonProcess process-name user=user group=group threads=10 python-path=vitrual-env-path
WSGIProcessGroup process-group
```

You can also alternatively (unless there aren't any other permission/group problems.) just add the relevant path read/write accesses to the user running the apache process.

```
chmod [apache-user]+rw /etc/httpd/logs/
```

Comment: Actually I checked the wsgi log file and it was `srwx------   1 apache    0 Feb 28 07:14 wsgi.17555.5.1.sock`. Doesn't that mean `apache` already have read/write permissions?

Comment: Also I'm confused on your `chmod` command. You can set to a file permission to a specific user, in this case `apache`?? The apache user and group is `apache` by the way. I don't know how to find out my virtual python environment (or if we are even using one).

Comment: If you are not using virtual-env, you can safely ignore that part. If you don't know, you are probably not.

Comment: Thanks for the help. What about the `threads=10` part? So am I suppose to use `user=user` or did you meant `user=apache` in my case? I need to read up more about this lol.

Comment: "chmod [apache-user]+rw /etc/httpd/logs/" that's not how to allow apache-user to enter the directory. It needs r+x.